# How to transfer paid android apps from one google account to another google account

Tags: android, transfer, account

I am developing a SYSTEM app for android to manage user accounts on the device.

Is there a way to PROGRAMMATICALLY transfer paid user apps from one account to the other?

Any help is appreciated (even if the reply does not directly target a solution).

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Google has this to say on transferring data between accounts.

http://support.google.com/accounts/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=63304

It lists certain types of data that **CAN** be transferred and certain types of data that **CAN NOT** be transferred. Unfortunately Google Play Apps falls into the **NOT** category.

It's conveniently titled: "Moving Product Data"

http://support.google.com/accounts/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=58582

Answer (score 5):

You will not be able to do that.  You can download apps again to the same userid account on different devices, but you cannot transfer those licenses to other userids.

There is no way to do this programatically - I don't think you can do that practically (except for trying to call customer support at the Play Store).

Answer (score -3):

It's totally feasible now. Google now allow you to transfer Android apps between accounts. Please take a look at this link:
https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/checklist/3294213?hl=en

Comment: I think the OP was asking how to transfer apps that you bought and not apps that you developed.

Answer (score -10):

You should be able to transfer the Application to another Username. You would need all your old user information to transfer it. The application would remove it's self from old account to new account. Also you could put a limit on how many times you where allowed to transfer it. If you transfer it to the application could expire after a year and force to buy update.

Comment: lovely idea, but this is NOT how it works. your reply is not an answer and shouldn't have been posted as one.

Comment: @jack his "answer" is worded in the form of a suggestion, as if he were making a feature request. Thus he was not attempting to post a factual answer, but rather voicing an opinion. His input would have been better delivered as a comment, in the manor that this very exchange between the two of us isn't being posted as answers. I know this is coming across as high horse, but people really should read the rules of the website before posting.